# Hazelcast IMDG 3.12.5 adding log4j dependency to support logging

Tags: log4j, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

i have followed the hazelcast docs for supporting log4j using below link:

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#logging-configuration

but even after doing so i am not able to get hazelcast logs.

queries:

1. do we explicitly need to add log4j-1.2.17.jar file and add this dependency to pom.xml file? if yes
   please let me know what is missing in hazelcast docs
2. is it possible to troubleshoot and check what is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a note in the Hazelcast reference manual section you've shared. It explains the thing:

> If you choose to use `log4j`, `log4j2`, or `slf4j`, you should include the proper dependencies in the classpath.

It means, yes. If you use a logging framework different from the `java.util.logging`, then you have to provide the implementation yourself.

If you don't provide the proper implementation, the node fails to start:

```sh
java -Dhazelcast.logging.type=log4j -jar \
    ~/.m2/repository/com/hazelcast/hazelcast/3.12.5/hazelcast-3.12.5.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at com.hazelcast.logging.Log4jFactory.createLogger(Log4jFactory.java:29)
    at com.hazelcast.logging.LoggerFactorySupport$1.createNew(LoggerFactorySupport.java:32)
    at com.hazelcast.logging.LoggerFactorySupport$1.createNew(LoggerFactorySupport.java:30)
    at com.hazelcast.util.ConcurrencyUtil.getOrPutIfAbsent(ConcurrencyUtil.java:125)
    at com.hazelcast.logging.LoggerFactorySupport.getLogger(LoggerFactorySupport.java:38)
    at com.hazelcast.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:110)
    at com.hazelcast.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.<clinit>(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:67)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:91)
    at com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

`log4j` is deprecated since 5 years ago, has security vulnerabilities and may not work on newer versions of Java. See [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/).

Specifying `hazelcast.logging.type` as `log4j` indicates to Hazelcast to use whatever Log4j it finds at runtime, as this enables you to chose the version you want.

So your pom needs to build an executable Jar including at least the Hazelcast jar and Log4j jar. Or, you put both on the classpath for runtime.

For me, 3.12.5 fails immediately with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
```

if I request Log4j but don't provide a Log4j jar on the runtime classpath. If you
don't get that message it could be that the configuration you specified isn't being used.